# App: App has multiple views and activities. Check how many times user went to a particular screen/view/activity

Tags: android

App: App has multiple views and activities. how to Check that how many times user went to a particular screen/view/activity in android

Comment: use flag variable in each activity and increment it when user enter's in screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Analytics SDK for Android v3 (Beta)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/?hl=es). It will give you what you want and much other nice features.

> The Google Analytics SDK for Android makes it easy for native Android
>   developers to collect user engagement data from their applications.
>   Developers can then use the Google Analytics reports to measure:
>
> - The number of active users are using their applications. From where
> - in the world the application is being used. Adoption and usage of
> - specific features. Crashes and exceptions. In-app purchases and
> - transactions. And many other useful metrics...